# Not able to connect to internet/repo through proxy

Tags: java, proxy, http-proxy, cuba-platform, cuba

I use a java framework to develop a crud application. This framework is called: "Cuba.Platform".

My problem is, that I am not able to open the project in cuba. 
When I try to open my project there, I get this problem:

“Repository contains cuba artifacts not found in https://repo.cuba-platform.com/content/groups/work”

I read a thread about a similar problem: 
https://www.cuba-platform.com/discuss/t/not-able-to-connect-to-internet-repo-through-proxy/387

But my question is, how I can modify it? How can I access to my project even through the proxy server?

They explain that I should set the JAVA_OPS variable, but how? I dont know how to do it, and not find something useful, that could explain me so, that I could understand it.

If someone could help me out, I would be very happy.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows, open **This PC (Context menu) > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment variables** and add the following variable:

Name: `JAVA_OPTS`

Value: `"-Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.1.1" "-Dhttp.proxyPort=3128" "-Dhttps.proxyHost=192.168.1.1" "-Dhttps.proxyPort=3128"`

Change your proxy address and port accordingly.

Comment: it still not works
I did the same way like you describe, I add a system variable in windows with this name. Then I start cuba studio and try to create new project and write the name of the project.

It loads and then I get this problem: unable to create project…

But the name of the project, which was “unable to create” is still shown on the browser under “projects”, when I click on it, it comes:

Repositiory containing cuba artefacts which can not be find …

in my home network, it works, but when I am in office, it dont. I have no idea anymore